# How do you find the missing side given an area and a portion of the unknown side?

Tags: triangles, area

I was given this homework while studying simmilar triangles and angle bisecotrs. The question states "find the missing length indicated and leave your answers in simple radical form." But I am confused as to how to solve it. Thank you for your help.

[image]

Comment: The picture is not much clear!

Comment: Why two lengths, $x$ and $64$, for the base side?

Comment: Both x and 64 are portions of the base.

Comment: @Boris there are three unknowns and two equations - suggest you revisit the question